# Typescript Mocha Chai-As-Promised: how to test a function that can throw OR return a Promise

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm testing a function to make sure it throws in certain situations.  If the func doesn't throw it returns a Promise.  For example:

```
function foo() {
  if ( true )
    throw new Error()

  return Promise.resolve()
}

describe( "", () => {
  it( "should throw", () => {
    foo.should.throw
  })
})
```

Works great except, if the func **doesn't** throw and instead returns a Promise, the test still passes.  Which has got me confused how my code will behave if it does/doesn't throw, and how to properly handle this.

I could switch it to an async function to force a Promise return, but then I end up with an async func with no awaits: bad.

Am I supposed to return a Promise.reject?  Does that mean I should **never** throw within a function that returns a Promise?  Ex:

```
function foo() {
  if ( true )
    return Promise.reject( new Error() )

  return Promise.resolve()
}

describe( "", () => {
  it( "should throw", async () => {
    foo().should.eventually.be.rejected
  })
})
```

If that's the case then I have a ton of throws I need to convert to rejects.  Thanks for your help and guidance on this!

Comment: just check if it pass with a `then()` and `.catch()` if it succeded the throw or not

Comment: @Sysix I'm not sure what you mean.  I can't call then() on a function that throws.  I could wrap the return value maybe and then use then?  Like Promise.resolve().then( foo ).should.eventually.be.rejected ?  I guess I'm more worried about the actual code behaving properly because I won't be wrapping the func like that when I use it elsewhere.

Comment: like this `foo().then(assertsFalse(false)).catch(assertTrue(true))`. Edit: in es5, in es6 you can use `try{}catch{}`

Comment: @Sysix thanks for the response, however as soon as you call foo() the unhandled exception will prevent anything else from happening.

Comment: then you need to sorround your code with `try {} catch {}` and specify the exception with `instanceof`. You can define your own sub classes of errors. An alternative is to use the rust variant. you can search for the npm package `ts-results` and look at the docs